# Проблемы с update запросом

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Есть таблица с 4 записями.
У меня есть массив с 2 подходящими мне записями из этой таблицы.
Я делаю update запрос ориентируясь по ним. В условии запроса есть пункт, что если записи не используются сейчас другими пользователями, то я могу сделать апдейт.

В общем если  записи не юзаются, то я успешно делаю свой запрос и юзаю их.

В самом update-запросе обновляется поле `date`, а в условии запроса идёт проверка, в которой мы сопоставляем текущую дату и дату из таблицы, и если различие есть в менее чем 5 минут между датами, то значит запись уже кем-то юзается.

И если одна запись или обе уже юзаются, то нужно чтобы скрипт опять попытался сделать запрос и присвоить себе записи, на случай если они освободятся конечно, и так до тех пор, пока мы не заюзаем записи.

Вот что я сейчас имею:

```
// Извлекаем все записи из rotation в массив

$Query123 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `first_name`, `uidvk`, `rot` FROM `rotation`");

$array = array();

while($Row123 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query123)) {
 $array[] = $Row123;
}
```

// тут будет проверка всех имеющихся записей к API ВКонтакте.
// Далее оставим в массиве только подходящие записи.

```
// Обновляем первые 2 попавшиеся записи в базе.

mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `rotation` SET `date` = NOW(), `yes` = '$_SESSION[USER_UIDVK]' WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) LIMIT 2"); // ну тут ещё будем ориентироваться както по обновлению записей только из массива.
```

// И вот если доступных для работы записей нет, то нужно проводить операцию всё время по новой. Пока не обновим 2 нужные записи.

// И вот ещё проблемка о которой я думаю заключается в том. что в будущем надо будет обновлять не 2 записи, а 10.
// и в том случае если 9 из 10 записей подходят для обновления, а одна не подходит, то нужно чтоб по второму кругу
// проблем никаких не сделалось, тобишь чтоб не обновилось уже 19 записей вместо 10. и нужно чтоб у всех было одно и то же время.

Помогите пожалуйста..

Comment: Вот подумал можно как-то в этот апдейт вставить после WHERE проверку на то. сколько доступно записей по нужным параметрам, и если доступно равно или больше необходимого нам значения. в примере это 2. то запросы проходят. если же не проходят, нужно по новой искать. подскажите пожалуйста можно ли реализовать такую проверку в запросе. и как в случае если запрос не прошёл повторять его до бесконечности пока не найдём что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
affected_rows_total = 0
do {
  affected_rows = do_query( Ваш скрипт обновления LIMIT 1);
  affected_rows_total += affected_rows;
} while affected_rows_total != 2
```

P.S. это всё sql-команда

**Обновление**

Всё просто. Мы знаем что нам надо обновить N строк. В мускуле заводим цикл обновление необходимых записей. При обновлении, нам возвращается количество затронутых строк. Мы их суммируем и смотрим: равна ли итоговая сумма затронутых строк числу строк, которые надо затронуть(N). Если да - выходим из цикла и прекращаем работу sql-скрипта.

Comment: а можете прокомментировать?